# JS cloneNode() and change the value of children

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe I've been staring at this too long. 
I'm trying to duplicate a node (a group of HTML) for each item in a dataset. Then for each node change the value of the node.children.children to the corresponding value from the dataset.

Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unitedideas/bgmzvfy5/109/).

Update: I cleared the cloned node and created elements and added the data and got it working. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unitedideas/bgmzvfy5/120/), But, I'm not happy with it.

update 2: I do have to remove these at some point too. Should I just build these nodes with each dataset? I'm receiving data axios per keystroke (live search).

What I would like to know is if there is a better way. A way that is easier to read/ maintain in the case the dataset ever expands past just these 3 items. If it does expand, someone would have to go back in and change the list and variables (prop_list)

Here are the JS and HTML as someone suggested:

```js
member_list = [{
      "model": "members.rider",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Shane",
        "lastName": "Cheek",
        "phoneNumber": "222-222-2222",
        "email": "Shane@email.com",
        "active": true
      }
    }, {
      "model": "members.rider",
      "pk": 2,
      "fields": {
        "firstName": "Other",
        "lastName": "Rider",
        "phoneNumber": "333-333-3333",
        "email": "Other@email.com",
        "active": false
      }
    }]
    
    
    
    for (let i in member_list) {
      let name = member_list[i].fields.firstName + " " + member_list[i].fields.lastName;
      let phoneNumber = member_list[i].fields.phoneNumber;
      let email = member_list[i].fields.email;
    
     let prop_list = [name, phoneNumber, email]
    
      let result_block = document.querySelector("#result_block");
      let result_group = document.querySelector("#result_group");
      let member_data = document.querySelector("#member_data_left");
    
    
      let cloned_result_group = result_group.cloneNode(true);
      result_block.appendChild(cloned_result_group);
      cloned_result_group.style.display = ""
      
      let cloned_member_data = cloned_result_group.querySelector("#member_data_left")
     cloned_member_data.innerHTML=""
        for (let p in prop_list) {
          let para = document.createElement("p")
          let text = document.createTextNode(prop_list[p])
          para.appendChild(text)
          cloned_member_data.appendChild(para)
        }
      }
```

```html
  
      <div class="result_block ref" id="result_block">
        <div class="result_group ref " id="result_group" style="display: none">
          <div class="member_data_left" id="member_data_left">
            <p id="first_last_name">name</p>
            <p id="phone">phone number</p>
            <p id="email">email</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I recommend putting your code directly into the question as a snippet instead of in a JSFiddle.

Comment: It is quite difficult to track the location of the problem. Can you post a [MCVE] to reduce the code?

Comment: I've provided the minimum code that I could provide. I tried working through the problem and this is the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really check out templating libraries like [handlebars.js](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/). They are designed to solve that exact problem you have, in the most efficient and maintainable way.

If you really want to implement it yourself, I suggest you work with strings rather than a Node instance, and minimize the DOM manipulation (`appendChild` or `some_node.innerHTML = '...'`), because that is the most expensive operation for the browser. You can copy the html of your template, and manipulate as a string before you create nodes.

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6bmjyneq/

```
let result_block = document.getElementById("result_block")
let result_group_template = document.getElementById("result_group_template").innerHTML
let new_results = []
for ( let i = 0; i < member_list.length; i++ ) {
    let this_result = result_group_template
    for( let field_name in member_list[i].fields ){
        this_result = this_result.replace( field_name, member_list[i].fields[field_name] )
    }
    new_results.push( this_result )
}
result_block.innerHTML = new_results.join("")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Concise and understandable. Using a reusable template  was my first thought as well. And I think it’s the best path. I just didn’t figure out how to implement it before moving on to this solution. I am using Django and at first I was thinking I would try and use the Django include template rendering. This application is so small and I’m using it to learn, I do want to implement it myself instead of using another library.

Comment: Hugo can you point me in the right direction to read up on {{${field_name}}} I've never seen it. What's the nomenclature? I see that it replaces the html from the template. It looks like Django template language. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/      Django uses {{}} for it's python template language. I will have to figure out how to use something else wither designated on the django side or the JS side.

Comment: Nevermind on the brackets {{}} I understand it now. It was really just a placeholder to legibility.

Comment: This is a great solution to the question it evolved to. Before I close it, should I change the actual question to something like. How to reuse template HTML with Javascript?

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Yeah, I think you should mention reusable template in the question for future reference

Comment: thanks again, you got me back on track! See Update 3 above for what I ended up doing. I had to clone the template because I needed to revert back to it when the user cleared the search terms (async calls to the backend on keyed input). Thank again man I learned a lot...and to not over think it.